# Tomcat memory information

Tags: performance, memory, tomcat, resources

i wrote a little test programm which queries the status servlet of a tomcat an fetches the memory information of the jvm (free,total,max). Is there a way to get more information ?
Like CPU, memory of the process, system memory and so on. I know that some of these things may possible to get somehow because there are tools (e.g. probe) which can fetch more information. What i want to achieve is to build maybe an ant task which i can call(is there maybe an better approach or already something ready to use?), which log's as much information for the time being. Any information/help would be appreceated. Thanks.

kukudas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull out a great deal using [JMX](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/mntr-mgmt/javamanagement/) , Tomcat has some [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/monitoring.html) on how to enable JMX, and also ant tasks for querying the management beans.

Try hook up [jconsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html) to Tomcat after you've enabled JMX,  you can browse all the management information available from a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with only the base libraries, but you can get all you want and more with the **[SIGAR API](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home)**. Some examples of things you can get:

- System memory, swap, cpu, load average, uptime, logins
- Per-process memory, cpu, credential info, state, arguments, environment, open files
- File system detection and metrics
- Network interface detection, configuration info and metrics
- TCP and UDP connection tables
- Network routing tables

Comment: You know of a similar lib with a apache licence?

Comment: SIGAR is licensed under GPL v3, which is compatible with Apache licensing.

Comment: Don't i have to licence my software also under GPL if i use a lib which is GPL ?